# Query returns same result three times

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get my website to show all the entries based on the "Country" criteria. Here is my code:

pertaining code for Default.aspx:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
                DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT Country, COUNT (*) AS N FROM [Table2] GROUP BY Country">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
     <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server">
           <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="countriesList"/>

           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Countries.aspx?Country="+ Eval("Country")%>'>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' /> (<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("N") %>' />)
               </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:DataList>
```

And here is the code for Countries.aspx:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table2 INNER JOIN [BlogEntryItems] ON Table2.ID=BlogEntryItems.BlogID WHERE Country=@Country" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Country" QueryStringField="Country" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
    runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="picTableStyle"
    DataKeyField="Country">
    <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <br /><br />
        <table>
            <tr>        
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Places.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")%>'>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="picTitleStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BlogTitle") %>' /><br /></asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" class="picBodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TravelDate", "{0:MMMMMMMMM dd, yyyy}") %>' /><br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" class="picBodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PicText") %>' />                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Places.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")%>'>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                    BorderWidth="1px" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("Image") %>' />
                    </asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

My problem is that it shows the same record in the database however many blog posts are about that country, i.e. I have three blog posts about Italy and two for Turkey. When I click on Italy, I get three of the same record (for some reason it picked record number 4, which is the middle record). If I pick Turkey, it shows two of the same record (record number 1). Any ideas on how to make the three and two different records show?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that all I had to do was remove the JOIN clause. Everything that I needed for Countries.aspx was in Table2. I had copied and pasted the query from another part of my site and didn't take out the JOIN clause.

Answer (score 1):

In Countries.aspx:
replace:

```
inner JOIN
```

with:

```
left JOIN
```

**Note:** you must use one-to-one Relationship by Table2.ID and BlogEntryItems.BlogID

Comment: Hey Samiey, you are kinda like my mentor, lol. I appreciate your responses. This time I figured that I didn't need the JOIN clause at all, as I stated below. I'll certainly upvote your answer though. Thanks again!